# Error from main arraylist GUI program. Not Sure how to fix it

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on an assignment for my java class. We were given two main programs to test our programs on. The main GUI is getting an error i'm not sure how fix.
I'm not allowed to make any changes to the two main programs at all. Note: I had this exact same error on my previous assignment for that assignments mainGUI class. My professor told me it was because of my toString method and it was creating at huge string that was way too long. Not sure if that's the same case here.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
CardArrayMasterGUI.java:117: error: constructor Point in class Point cannot be applied to given types;
      frame.setLocation(new Point(100, 100));
                        ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

This is the main GUI program:

```
import java.awt.*; // for Dimension
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; // for GUI components 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

/** CS145
 * Class CardArrayMasterGUI is the driver program for the List program.  It reads a
 * dictionary of words to be used during the game and then asks the user to create a
 * data structure to sort through them.
 *
 * <p>This version uses a GUI to force students to not have access to the console.
 *
 * <p><B>
 * STUDENTS SHOULD NOT MODIFY THIS PROGRAM IN ANY WAY.
 * </B>
 * @author Michael A. Wood
 * @version 1.0
 */

public class CardArrayMasterGUI implements ActionListener  
{
   private boolean DEBUGMODE = false;
   private static final int STAGECOUNT = 13;
   private CardArrayList masterList1 = new CardArrayList();
   private PrintStream SO = System.out;  // Lazy mode  enabled;
    // GUI ELEMENTS
   private JFrame frame;
   private JButton button1;
   private JLabel[] text;
   private JTextArea[] textData;
   private JScrollPane[] textBox;
   private JComboBox<String> levelSelector;    
   private JCheckBox debugMode;

     /**  Main Program.
     *
     * @param args The OS parameters
     */
   public static void main(String[] args)  {
      CardArrayMasterGUI gui = new CardArrayMasterGUI();
   }

    /** CardArrayMasterGUI Constructor
     *  <p> This sets up the form and makes it visible
     *
     */
   public CardArrayMasterGUI()
   {

        // Call private method to set up the form.
      formSetup();

        // Open the frame.        
      frame.setVisible(true);

   }

     /**
      * This method responds to all events thrown by the various elements
      * of the GUI
      * @param event The action event thrown by the GUI
      */
   @Override 
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
   {
      resetAnswers();
      int x = levelSelector.getSelectedIndex() + 1; 
      if (event.getActionCommand().equals("debugMode"))
      {
         DEBUGMODE = debugMode.isSelected();
      }
      if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Start") || event.getActionCommand().equals("debugMode"))
      {
         stage0();
         masterList1 = new CardArrayList();
         stage1();
         if (x > 1) stage2();
         if (x > 2) stage3();
         if (x > 3) stage4();
         if (x > 4) stage5();
         if (x > 5) stage6();
         if (x > 6) stage7();
         if (x > 7) stage8();
         if (x > 8) stage9();
         if (x > 9) stage10();
         if (x > 10) stage11();
         if (x > 11) stage12();
         if (x > 12) stage13();

      }
   }

     /*
      * This method sets all the stage answers to a blank value
      */

   private void resetAnswers()
   { 
      for(int i = 0; i < STAGECOUNT; i++)
         textData[i].setText("NOTHING");
   }

     /*
      * set up the GUI form and all components.
      */
   private void formSetup()
   {
        // Window setup.      
      frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setLocation(new Point(100, 100));
      frame.setSize(new Dimension(800,800));
      frame.setTitle("Anagrams");
      frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

        // Start the process button
      button1 = new JButton();
      button1.setText("Start");
      button1.addActionListener(this );
      button1.setActionCommand("Start");

        // Setup the level checker
      String[] levels = new String[STAGECOUNT];
      for(int i = 0; i < STAGECOUNT; i++)
         levels[i] = "Stage " + (i+1);
      levelSelector = new JComboBox<String>(levels);

        // Output Text Fields
      text = new JLabel[STAGECOUNT];
      textData = new JTextArea[STAGECOUNT] ;
      textBox = new JScrollPane[STAGECOUNT] ;
      for(int i = 0; i < STAGECOUNT; i++)
      {
         text[i]     = new JLabel();
         text[i].setText("Stage " + (i+1) );
         textData[i] = new JTextArea();
         textData[i].setText("NOTHING");
         textBox[i]  = new JScrollPane(textData[i]);
      }


        // Debugging Radio Button
      debugMode = new JCheckBox();
      debugMode.setText("Debug Mode");
      debugMode.addActionListener(this );
      debugMode.setActionCommand("debugMode");    
      debugMode.setBounds(650, 10, 100,25);    



        // Add components to frame.
      frame.add(button1);
      frame.add(levelSelector);
      frame.add(debugMode);
      for(int i = 0; i < STAGECOUNT; i++)
      {
         frame.add(text[i]);
         frame.add(textBox[i]);
      }

        // Layout the frame.
        // null layout to demonstrate the idea.   
        // not using the default layouts to show the idea.
      frame.setLayout(null); 
      button1.setBounds(10,10,150,25);

      for(int i = 0; i < STAGECOUNT; i++)
      {
         text[i].setBounds(10, 50+(45*i), 100,25);
         textBox[i].setBounds(110, 50+(45*i), 600,40);
      }

      levelSelector.setBounds(400, 10, 100,25);
   }


//**********************************************************************************
//**                          STAGE TESTING                                     ****     
//**********************************************************************************

   //****  STAGE 0 TESTING  *******
   // This tests to see if the proper exceptions
   // are thrown.

   public void stage0()
   {
      if(!DEBUGMODE) 
         return;
      System.out.println("Testing Exceptions");
      try
      {
         Card xx = new Card(1001,1001);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"FAILED Exception Catching");
         System.exit(0);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         System.out.println("PASSED Stage 0");
      }
   }

     //****  STAGE 1 TESTING  *******
     //Can we add cards to the list?

   private void stage1()
   {

      masterList1.add(new Card());     
      masterList1.add(new Card(20));     
      masterList1.add(new Card(10,10));
      String x ="Initial list   : ";
      x += masterList1;
      textData[0].setText(x); 

      if(DEBUGMODE)
         if (masterList1.size() == 3 && masterList1.toString().contains("],[20/20],[10/10]")) 
           SO.println("PASSED STAGE 1"); 
         else SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 1");

   }

     //****  STAGE 2 TESTING  *******
     //Do premium cards work?

   private void stage2()
   {
      masterList1.add(new PremiumCard(100));     
      String x = "Premium Card   : "; 
      x += masterList1;
      textData[1].setText(x);
      if(DEBUGMODE)
         if (masterList1.toString().contains(",{{100/100}}")) 
            SO.println("PASSED STAGE 2"); 
         else SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 2");
   }

    //****  STAGE 3 TESTING  *******
    //Can we add cards in the middle??
    // .add(#, card)

   private void stage3()
   {
      masterList1.add(1, new Card(4,4));
      masterList1.add(1, new Card(5,5));
      String x = "Added internal : "; 
      x +=  masterList1;    
      textData[2].setText(x);

      if(DEBUGMODE)
         if (masterList1.toString().contains(",[5/5],[4/4],[20/20],")) 
            SO.println("PASSED STAGE 3"); 
         else SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 3");
   }     

    //****  STAGE 4 TESTING  *******
    //can we add more cards and make it expand 
    //past the initial array size?

   private void stage4()
   {
      masterList1.add(new Card(6));
      masterList1.add(new Card(7));
      masterList1.add(new Card(8));
      masterList1.add(new Card(9));
      masterList1.add(new Card(10));
      masterList1.add(new Card(11));
      masterList1.add(new Card(12));
      String x = "After Expand   : "; 
      x +=  masterList1 ;
      textData[3].setText(x);

      if(DEBUGMODE)
         if (masterList1.toString().endsWith(":13]")) 
            SO.println("PASSED STAGE 4"); 
         else SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 4");
   }

    //****  STAGE 5 TESTING  *******
    //Does remove work?  
    //does it remove the last element?

   private void stage5()
   {
      masterList1.remove();
      String x = "After Remove   : "; 
      x +=  masterList1 ;
      textData[4].setText(x);
      if(DEBUGMODE)
         if (masterList1.toString().endsWith(":12]")) 
            SO.println("PASSED STAGE 5"); 
         else SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 5");
   }

    //****  STAGE 6 TESTING  *******
    //Does remove RETURN the object removed?

   private void stage6()
   {
      String x = "Removed value  : "; 
      Card tmp = masterList1.remove() ;
      x +=  tmp ;
      x +=  " -- List afterward : "; 
      x +=  masterList1 ;
      textData[5].setText(x);

      if(DEBUGMODE)
         if (tmp.toString().equals("[11/11]")) 
            SO.println("PASSED STAGE 6"); 
         else SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 6");
   }

   //****  STAGE 7 TESTING  *******
   //Did it remove from the middle of the list?
   // And return the value removed?

   private void stage7()
   {
      Card tmp = masterList1.remove(2);
      if(DEBUGMODE)
         if (tmp.toString().equals("[4/4]"))  
            SO.println("PASSED STAGE 7A"); 
         else SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 7A");

      String x = "Removed value  : "; 
      x += tmp ;
      x += " -- List afterward : "; 
      x += masterList1;
      textData[6].setText(x);

      if(DEBUGMODE)
         if (masterList1.toString().contains(",[5/5],[20/20],")) 
            SO.println("PASSED STAGE 7B"); 
         else SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 7B");
   }

   //****  STAGE 8 TESTING  *******
   //Does the GET command work correctly?
   //Does weaken and boost work correctly?

   private void stage8()
   {
      String x = "Get Values     : "; 
      x += masterList1.get(2) + " : " + masterList1.get(4) ;

      if(DEBUGMODE)
         if (x.contains("[20/20] : {{100/100}}")) 
            SO.println("PASSED STAGE 8A"); 
         else SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 8a");

      masterList1.get(2).weaken();
      masterList1.get(4).boost();
      x += "  Altered Values : "; 
      String xx = masterList1.get(2) + " : " + masterList1.get(4) ; 
      x += xx;
      textData[7].setText(x);

      if(DEBUGMODE)
         if (xx.contains("[18/18] : {{110/110}}")) 
            SO.println("PASSED STAGE 8B"); 
         else SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 8b");

   }

   //****  STAGE 9 TESTING  *******
   //Does the indexOF command work correctly?
   //Does weaken and boost work correctly?

   private void stage9()
   {
      String x = "";

      x+="Card {{110,110}} Should be at (4)->";
      x+=masterList1.indexOf(new Card(110,110));
      x+="  ,  Card (9,9) Should be at (8)->";
      x+=masterList1.indexOf(new Card(9,9)); 
      x+="  ,  Card (600,600) Should be at (-1)->";
      x+=masterList1.indexOf(new Card(600,600));
      x+= " ";
      textData[8].setText(x);

      if(DEBUGMODE)
         if (masterList1.indexOf(new Card(110,110)) == 4 &&
           masterList1.indexOf(new Card(600,600)) == -1 &&
           masterList1.indexOf(new Card(9,9)) == 8)       
            SO.println("PASSED STAGE 9"); 
         else SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 9");


   }

   //****  STAGE 10 TESTING  *******
   //Does shuffle work correctly?
   //Note: this does not autograde.  Check it manually.

   private void stage10()
   {
      String x = "";
      x += "Before shuffle : ";
      x += masterList1;
      masterList1.shuffle();
      x += "    Post shuffle 1 : ";
      x += (masterList1);
      masterList1.shuffle();
      x += ("   Post shuffle 2 : ");
      x += masterList1 ; 

      textData[9].setText(x);

      if(DEBUGMODE)
         SO.println("STAGE 10 - Check manually"); 

   }

   //****  STAGE 11 TESTING  *******
   //Does clear work correctly?

   private void stage11()
   {
          // STAGE 11
          // Does Clear Work?
      String x = "";
      masterList1.clear();
      x += ("After Clear    : ");
      x += (masterList1);
      textData[10].setText(x);

      if(DEBUGMODE)
         if (masterList1.size() == 0 && masterList1.toString().equals("[0: :0]"))
            SO.println("PASSED STAGE 11"); 
         else SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 11");

   }

   //****  STAGE 12 TESTING  *******
   //Does sort work correctly.
   //Note this expects the sort to go from HIGH to LOW.
   //This tests the SORT and the CARD

   private void stage12()
   {
      // STAGE 12
      // Create a large list
      // And check that sort works.

      for (int i=0; i <100; i++)
      {
         masterList1.add(new Card());
      }
      for (int i=0; i <5; i++)
      {
         masterList1.add(new PremiumCard());
      }

      masterList1.sort();

      String x = "";
      x+="Success Sorted : ";
      x+=masterList1;
      textData[11].setText(x);

      if(DEBUGMODE)
      {
         boolean pass = true;
         String error = "";
         for (int j = 0; j <masterList1.size() - 1; j++)
         {
          //SO.print(masterList1.get(j).getCost());
          //SO.print("-");
            if (masterList1.get(j).getCost() < masterList1.get(j+1).getCost() )
            {
               pass = false;

               error += (" " + masterList1.get(j)+"("+masterList1.get(j).getCost()+")" +"::" 
                       + masterList1.get(j+1)+"("+masterList1.get(j+1).getCost()+")");
            }
         }
          //SO.println(masterList1.get(masterList1.size()-1).getCost());;
         if (pass) SO.println("PASSED STAGE 12"); 
         else 
         { 
            SO.println("   FAILED STAGE 12  -- ");
            SO.println(error);
         }
      }

   }

   //****  STAGE 13 TESTING  *******
   // Can we create a second list
   // and make a copy of all NON premium cards   
   //Note: this does not autograde.  Check it manually.

   private void stage13()
   {
      CardArrayList masterList2 = new CardArrayList(1);
      for (int j = 0; j <masterList1.size(); j++)
      {
         if (!(masterList1.get(j) instanceof PremiumCard))
         {
            masterList2.add(masterList1.get(j) );
         }
      }
      String x = ("Success Removed: ");
      x += (masterList2);

      textData[12].setText(x);

      if(DEBUGMODE)
         SO.println("STAGE 13 - Check manually"); 
   }
}
```

Here are the programs I implemented:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Card {

   private int power;
   private int toughness;

   public Card() {
      power = new Random().nextInt(1000);
      toughness = new Random().nextInt(1000);
   }

   public Card(int x) {
      if (x <= 1 && x >= 1000) {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      } 
      else {
         power = x;
         toughness = x;
      }
   }

   public Card(int p, int t) {
      this.power = p;
      this.toughness = t;
      if ((p <= 1 && p >= 1000) || (t <= 1 && t >= 1000)) {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      } 
   }

   public int getPower() {
      return power;
   }

   public int getToughness() {
      return toughness;
   }

   public int getCost() {
      return (int) Math.abs(Math.pow(((1.1 * power) + (0.75 * toughness)), (3 / 4)));
   }

   public String toString() {
      return "[" + power + "/" + toughness + "]";
   }

   public void weaken() {
      power = (int) (power - power * 0.1);
      toughness = (int) (toughness - toughness * 0.1);
   }

   public void boost() {
      power = (int) (power + power * 0.1);
      toughness = (int) (toughness + toughness * 0.1);
   }

   public int compareTo(Card x) {
      int cost = (int) Math.abs(Math.pow(((1.1 * power) + (0.75 * toughness)), (3 / 4)));
      if(x == null) return -1;
      if(this.equals(x)) return 0;
      else if(cost == x.getCost()) {
         if(power == x.getPower()) return 0;
         else if(power < x.getPower()) return -1;
         else return 1;
      }
      else if(cost > x.getCost()) return 1;
      else return -1;
   }
}
```

```
public class PremiumCard extends Card{

   public PremiumCard() {
      super();
   }

   public PremiumCard(int x) {
      super(x);
   }

   public PremiumCard(int p, int t) {
      super(p, t);
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "{{" + getPower() + "/" + getToughness() + "}}";
   }
}
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class CardArrayList {

   private Card cards[];
   private int size;
   private Random random;

   public CardArrayList() {
      cards = new Card[10];
      random = new Random();
      clear();
   }

   public CardArrayList(int x) {
      random = new Random();
      if(x>=1) {
         cards = new Card[x];
         size = 0;
      }
      else throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
   }

   public int size() {
      return size;
   }

   public void add(Card x) {
      if(!isRoom()) expand();
      cards[size++] = x;
   }

   public Card remove() {
      Card card = cards[size-1];
      size--;
      return card;
   }

   public Card remove(int j) {
      if(j<0 || j>size-1) {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      }
      else {
         Card card = cards[j];
         for(int i=j; i<size-1; i++) {
            cards[i] = cards[i+1];
         }
         size--;
         return card;
      }
   }

   public Card get(int x) {
      if(x<0 || x>size-1) {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      }
      else return cards[x];
   }

   public int indexOf(Card card) {
      for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
         if(cards[i].equals(card)) return i;
      }
      return -1;
   }

   public void add(int l, Card x)
   {
       if(l>0 && l<cards.length)
       {
           if(!isRoom())
               expand();
           if(l<size-1)
           {
               for(int i=size; i>l; i--)
               {
                   cards[i] = cards[i-1];
               }
               cards[l] = x;
           }
           else
           {
               cards[l] = x;
           }
           size++;
       }
       else
           throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Index value is out of bounds");
   }

   private void swap(int a, int b)
   {
       Card x = cards[a];
       cards[a] = cards[b];
       cards[b] = x;
   }

   public void sort() {
       for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
       {
           for(int j=i; j<size; j++)
           {
               if(cards[i].compareTo(cards[j]) == -1)
                   swap(i, j);
           }
       }
   }

   public void shuffle()
   {
       int i = 0, times = size*5;
       while(i<times)
       {
           int a = random.nextInt(size);
           int b = random.nextInt(size);
           swap(a, b);
           i++;
       }

   }

   private boolean isRoom()
   {
       return size<cards.length;
   }

   private void expand()
   {
       Card newCards[] = new Card[cards.length*2];
       for(int i=0; i<cards.length; i++)
           newCards[i] = cards[i];
       cards = newCards;
   }

   public void clear()
   {
       size = 0;
       cards = new Card[10];
   }

   public String toString() {
       String result = "[0: ";
       for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
       {
           result += cards[i];
           if(i<size-1)
               result += ",";
       }
       result += " :" + size + "]";
       return result;
   }
}
```

Here is the other main program which seems to work just fine with my programs:

```
/*
 * CS 145
 *
 * Card Array Master is a generic class usefull for you to test your 
 * CardArrayList class.   At the beginning it is heavily commented out
 * but as you get more and more working, you can remove sections
 * to test various things out.
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CardArrayMaster {

    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     PrintStream SO = System.out;  // Lazy mode  enabled;

     // STAGE 1
     // Can we add to a master list and print it out?
     CardArrayList masterList1 = new CardArrayList();
     masterList1.add(new Card());     
     masterList1.add(new Card(10,10));
     SO.print("Initial list   : "); 
     SO.println(masterList1);     

     // STAGE 2
     // Can we add a premium card? 
     masterList1.add(new PremiumCard(100));     
     SO.print("Premium Card   : "); 
     SO.println(masterList1);

     // STAGE 3
     // Can we add cars in the middle?

     masterList1.add(1, new Card(4,4));
     masterList1.add(1, new Card(5,5));
     SO.print("Added internal : "); 
     SO.println(masterList1);

     // STAGE 4
     // can we add more cards and make it expand?

     masterList1.add(new Card(6));
     masterList1.add(new Card(7));
     masterList1.add(new Card(8));
     masterList1.add(new Card(9));
     masterList1.add(new Card(10));
     masterList1.add(new Card(11));
     masterList1.add(new Card(12));
     SO.print("After Expand   : "); 
     SO.println(masterList1);

     // STAGE 5
     // Can we Remove the end value
     masterList1.remove();
     SO.print("After Remove   : "); 
     SO.println(masterList1);

     // STAGE 6
     // Does remove return the removed value?

     SO.print("Removed value  : "); 
     SO.println(masterList1.remove() );
     SO.print("List afterward : "); 
     SO.println(masterList1);

     // STAGE 7
     // Did it remove from the middle
     // And return the value removed?
     Card tmp = masterList1.remove(2);
     SO.print("Removed value  : "); 
     SO.println(tmp);
     SO.print("List afterward : "); 
     SO.println(masterList1);

     // STAGE 8
     // Did get work correctly?
     SO.print("Get Values     : "); 
     SO.println(masterList1.get(2) + " : " + masterList1.get(4) );
     masterList1.get(2).weaken();
     masterList1.get(4).boost();
     SO.print("Altered Values : "); 
     SO.println(masterList1.get(2) + " : " + masterList1.get(4) );    

     // STAGE 9
     // IndexOF

     SO.print("Found Success  : ");
     SO.println(masterList1.indexOf(new Card(110,110)));
     SO.print("Found Failed   : ");
     SO.println(masterList1.indexOf(new Card(99,99))); 
     SO.print("Found Failed   : ");
     SO.println(masterList1.indexOf(new Card(600,600)));

     // STAGE 10
     // Does shuffle work?
     SO.print("Before shuffle : ");
     SO.println(masterList1);
     masterList1.shuffle();
     SO.print("Post shuffle 1 : ");
     SO.println(masterList1);
     masterList1.shuffle();
     SO.print("Post shuffle 2 : ");
     SO.println(masterList1);

     // STAGE 11
     // Does Clear Work?
     masterList1.clear();
     SO.print("After Clear    : ");
     SO.println(masterList1);

     // STAGE 12
     // Create a large list
     // And check that sort works.

     for (int i=0; i <100; i++)
     {
       masterList1.add(new Card());
     }
     for (int i=0; i <5; i++)
     {
       masterList1.add(new PremiumCard());
     }

     SO.print("Before Sorted  : ");
     SO.println(masterList1);
     masterList1.sort();
     SO.print("Success Sorted : ");
     SO.println(masterList1);

     // STAGE 13
     // Can we create a second list
     // and make a copy of all NON premium cards

     CardArrayList masterList2 = new CardArrayList(1);

     for (int j = 0; j <masterList1.size(); j++)
     {
       if (!(masterList1.get(j) instanceof PremiumCard))
       {
         masterList2.add(masterList1.get(j) );
       }
     }

     SO.print("Success Removed: ");
     SO.println(masterList2);
   }
}
```

Comment: I get no errors at compile- or run-time when running your code using the `CardArrayMasterGUI` class.  The error you're getting looks to me like you've got a class named `Point` somewhere that's being picked up in your classpath before `java.awt.Point`.

Comment: How, exactly, are you compiling and running your code?  The format of the error text makes it look like you're running javac from a command prompt.  If so, please [edit] your question to include the full javac command, and also include any CLASSPATH environment variable you might have.  If you're using an IDE, let us know which one.

Comment: Your GUI is loading fine. I too got no errors. Tried it on IntelliJ - just copy pasted. @azurefrog's point is correct. You Point class is getting picked from somewhere else.

Comment: try `new java.awt.Point(100, 100)`

Comment: That was the problem. I had a point class for something else that was screwing it up. Thanks everyone!